# need to get a GET variable then send it thru ajax jquery

Tags: jquery

how can you get a GET variable with javascript?
i get it in php from the query string:
$idmessage = $_GET['id'];

then need to send it in  $.ajax()  jquery, how can i do this? 
regards

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, _GET is strictly for getting references from the query string?

Comment: You're trying to get a variable that was passed in the request of the page?

Comment: yes Shaded, that is.,  yes GET is for getting refs from the query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET variables do not exist on clientside. You need to parse `document.location.href`. You can make a shortcut with [this](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2006/10/28/jquery-plugin-geturlparam/), I believe, if you're using jQuery as you say.

Comment: yes good one, i succeedeed to get the GET var but by echoing the javascript, parsing location.href looks like the real solution here